# How to send RUN's output to ENV in Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I have the following command in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
RUN apk add curl 
RUN ABCD=$(curl https://aaaa.bbbb.com/pf/ABCD) \
    && echo $ABCD
    && export ABCD="$ABCD"
ENV ABCD ${ABCD}
VOLUME /tmp
COPY target/*.jar app.jar

EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

After deploying the pod when I tried to execute the "env" command inside the container it show the blank output like "ABCD=".

It should store the env variable as "ABCD=output of curl command".

Please help me to achieve this or suggest other way to achieve this.

Comment: Dockerfile `ENV` doesn't support command substitution, but it's the only way to set a persistent environment variable, so this isn't really possible.  You could `RUN` a script to write the value into a file, then re-read it in an entrypoint wrapper script.